# How to correctly install the python RPi.GPIO library

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I downloaded RPi.GPIO 5.3a from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO

I extracted the tar file, cd into the folder and ran:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

It ran through a bunch of stuff and doesn't seem to have failed. The last line of its work is this:

```
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RPi.GPIO-0.5.3a.egg-info
```

After that it was done and gave me back control.

Now I type

```
sudo python
```

then

```
import RPi.GPIO
```

and I see

```
ImportError: No module named GPIO
```

Can anyone point me to exactly what steps I need to take to get the python GPIO library installed correctly so I can import it and manipulate the GP pins? I've found a mish mash of different processes online (this was the one that came up most often) but I have thus far been unable to get any of them to work.

Comment: the correct syntax is: import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

Comment: Here in the future, `RPi.GPIO`, and `gpiozero` are now installed by default in Raspbian. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/gpio-zero-update/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not sure if this is helpful, but under the latest copy of Raspbian I was able to install RPi.GPIO directly from the main repositories using apt-get as follows:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python-rpi.gpio
```

If you're running Python 3 (`idle3` on the command line) instead of Python 2 (`python` on the command line) you need to install the RPi.GPIO library with this command instead:

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-rpi.gpio
```

Comment: E: Package 'python-rpi.gpio' has no installation candidat

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you have pip, the python package index installer, which is installed on the latest versions of Raspbian by default
You can use: 
`sudo pip install RPi.GPIO` for Python 2
and 
`sudo pip-3.2 install RPi.GPIO` for Python 3

Answer (score 6):

Another potential cause could be because the `RPi.GPIO` library has C bindings and therefore need to have `python-dev` installed in order to compile correctly when installing.

Make sure you've got the `python-dev` package installed along with the `RPi.GPIO` package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-rpi.gpio
```

This is the recommended approach on the Adafriuit installation guide:

https://learn.adafruit.com/playing-sounds-and-using-buttons-with-raspberry-pi/install-python-module-rpi-dot-gpio

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a fresh image you don’t need to install it.

For the old version

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install rpi.gpio

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on my RPi 4B. Just ensure you have the last version of RPi.GPIO but installed from pip (it was newer) than apt-get:

Remove current RPi.GPIO versions:

```
sudo apt-get purge python{,3}-rpi.gpio
```

Update pip first:

```
sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Install RPi.GPIO from updated pip:

```
python -m pip install RPi.GPIO
python3 -m pip install RPi.GPIO
```

Comment: There is NO NEED to install `RPi.GPIO` the latest version is included in *Raspberry Pi OS* and if you need to reinstall use the version in the repository. All you have achieved is resurrecting an obsolete post.

Comment: But it might be useful for people that are not running Raspberry Pi OS. In my case, I was running Ubuntu for full ROS compatibility and I needed RPi.GPIO.

Comment: @JosepClotetGinovart This sollution that you have posted resolved my problem. Thanks to you Bro